# What's the difference between these two constructors in java ? (Memory)

Tags: java, this

here in this code

```
public class Base {
    int length, breadth, height;

    Base(int l, int b, int h) {
        length = l;
        breadth = b;
        height = h;
    }
}
```

and

```
Base(int l, int b, int h) {
    this.length = l;
    this.breadth = b;
    this.height = h;
}
```

here what's the difference between this two constructors intialization?
which method is highly preferred?
how it varies in terms of memory allocation?

Comment: In short they are same

Comment: Personally I only use the this keyword when I have named the parameters the same as the variables I will be assigning it to. I don't think there is any memory preference for either.

Comment: Could it be that it makes the code clear that the second class is to be used for classes that are not static, but the first works with both static and not static?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no difference. In the first constructor you just omit `this` while in the second you explicitly specify it. Generated bytecode is exactly the same (you can check it). It's just a matter of style if you want to put this or not, unless the field has the same name as the parameter, in which case `this` is mandatory to avoid ambiguity, for example:

```
Base(int length,int breadth,int height) {
   this.length = length;
   this.breadth = breadth;
   this.height = height;
}
```

(Please use spaces wisely, it makes your code more readable).

Comment: I would add that *this* is useful when your formal parameters have the same name than your attributes since It allows you to differenciate the attribute and the parameter.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo I already stated that, please read the whole answer.

Comment: @SundypKrishna You're welcome, glad to have been helpful. Don't forget to mark the best answer as correct and welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same.
A difference would be if you write this:

```
Base(int length, int breadth, int height)
{
   this.length=length;
   this.breadth=breadth;
   this.height=height;
}
```

because there are two variables named length etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same. In the first case, compiler will implicitly add `this` keyword while compiling it.

The only difference is that seconds seems more readable. It easily differentiates member variables from local ones. Generally `this` comes in handy to refer member variables when local variables shadow them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, because `this` is implicitly added to the first constructor. In Java in terms of construtors there is a convention to use the second approach, because it's more readable and not as error prone as the first approach.

There is also no difference in memory allocation, because the byte code it exactly the same.

Comment: There are many conventions but always `this`-prefixing field access is in my experience not a very popular one because many people feel that it is less readable.

Comment: @zapl to specify I'm talking only about constructors

Comment: Even there. `this.` is often only used when required, e.g. when parameter and fields have exactly the same name (which is not the case in OPs example). Using the same name for both is no doubt a common schema but that requires the use of `this.` and it's not just convention. But making them different on purpose is also quite common. Ranging from prefixing fields like `mField` to parameters with suffixes like `foo(Type param_)`. Using `this.` in a constructor that has different names is in that case just superfluous.